# check email format and just English characters with lower characters

Tags: javascript

the presence of all dear friends
I have a Javascript form embedded in HTML that I will use to send emails. My problem is that I just want the email address to be in **English** and **lowercase**. Help if possible. Thank you for your attention and kindness friends. Of course, the presence of the @ character is also mandatory, which is also checked in the Java code text.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form Validation</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var divs = new Array();
    divs[0] = "errFirst";
    divs[1] = "errLast";
    divs[2] = "errEmail";
    divs[3] = "errUid";
    divs[4] = "errPassword";
    divs[5] = "errConfirm";
    function validate()
    {
      var inputs = new Array();
      inputs[0] = document.getElementById('first').value;
      inputs[1] = document.getElementById('last').value;
      inputs[2] = document.getElementById('email').value;
      inputs[3] = document.getElementById('uid').value;
      inputs[4] = document.getElementById('password').value;
      inputs[5] = document.getElementById('confirm').value;
      var errors = new Array();
      errors[0] = "<span style='color:red'>Please enter your first name!</span>";
      errors[1] = "<span style='color:red'>Please enter your last name!</span>";
      errors[2] = "<span style='color:red'>Please enter your email!</span>";
      errors[3] = "<span style='color:red'>Please enter your user id!</span>";
      errors[4] = "<span style='color:red'>Please enter your password!</span>";
      errors[5] = "<span style='color:red'>Please confirm your password!</span>";
      for (i in inputs)
      {
        var errMessage = errors[i];
        var div = divs[i];
        if (inputs[i] == "")
            document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = errMessage;
        else if (i==2)
        {
          var atpos=inputs[i].indexOf("@");
          var dotpos=inputs[i].lastIndexOf(".");
          if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=inputs[i].length)
            document.getElementById('errEmail').innerHTML = "<span style='color: red'>Enter a valid email address!</span>";
          else
            document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "OK!";
        }
        else if (i==5)
        {
          var first = document.getElementById('password').value;
          var second = document.getElementById('confirm').value;
          if (second != first)
            document.getElementById('errConfirm').innerHTML = "<span style='color: red'>Your passwords don't match!</span>";
          else
            document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "OK!";
        }
        else
            document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = "OK!";
       }
     }
        function finalValidate()
        {
          var count = 0;
          for(i=0;i<6;i++)
          {
            var div = divs[i];
            if(document.getElementById(div).innerHTML == "OK!")
            count = count + 1;
          }
          if(count == 6)
            document.getElementById("errFinal").innerHTML = "All the data you entered is correct!!!";
        }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="table1">
      <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="first" onkeyup="validate();" /></td>
        <td><div id="errFirst"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Last Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="last" onkeyup="validate();"/></td>
        <td><div id="errLast"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="email" onkeyup="validate();"/></td>
        <td><div id="errEmail"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>User Id:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="uid" onkeyup="validate();"/></td>
        <td><div id="errUid"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="password" onkeyup="validate();"/></td>
        <td><div id="errPassword"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Confirm Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="confirm" onkeyup="validate();"/></td>
        <td><div id="errConfirm"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" id="create" value="Create" onclick="validate();finalValidate();"/></td>
        <td><div id="errFinal"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Comment: Why are you asking about Java but showing JavaScript code and tagging JavaScript? Which one are you asking about? _“I just want the email address to be in English and lowercase”_ — What is the purpose of that? Valid e-mail addresses can contain characters that are uppercase or non-Latin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: @user3532758 Note that the accepted answer there is problematic.

Comment: @SebastianSimon yeah so says in the comments there too, but there are a number of good answers there.

Comment: thanks for your attention. how i can use validateEmail(email) in my codes? @user3532758

Comment: Hello Mr. @Barmar I mean javascript.

Comment: Sorry I mean javascript   @Sebastian Simon

Comment: @ترمیناتور Then simply [edit] your post…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|. 
    (".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA- 
    Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

Input[2] is email. While calculating errors array, use this function to check email. If valid email, it will return true, if not it will return false, in which case you store email error in your error array.

Comment: at fisrt thanks for your attention. how I can use validateEmail(email) it in my code? @aryan singh

Comment: just add function validateEmail(email)  into your project and call it and use with itemID.